# node postgres and getting joined fields with repeated names

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, postgresql

I'm writing a node.js app that uses the pg package for accessing a PostgreSQL database. The issue I'm running into is that if I do a query like this:

```
select * from posts p inner join blogs b on b.id = p.blog_id
```

When I get the results, they're all in the same namespace, so any field repeated in the blogs table will overwrite those in the posts table.

My question is, what's the best way of binding these results to objects?

Ideally, I'd like a result like:

```
{
   id: 1,
   name: 'A post name',
   published_at: (some date object),
   blog_id: 1,
   b: {
       id: 1,
       name: 'A blog name'
   }
}
```

But I'm open to any convenient solution short of adding an alias for every column manually.

Comment: Data-to-object mapping is done by ORM-s, which node-postgres isn't. You will have to do it manually.

Comment: @vitaly-t: I don't necessarily need it to be an object. Basically I just want all the tables returned to be namespaced so I can access all the fields without having to alias.

Comment: Did you found a workaround? I am encountering the same issue but none of responses seems to address the issue. The `pg` results contains a property `rows` where the results are merged and `fields` where they are distinct (but it's just the name of the columns, without the values).

Answer (score 5):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html

You may want to look at the json features of Postgres. If I'm understanding you right, and without a test database something like this may be close to what you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
    p.*, /* Select all the post fields */
    row_to_json(blogs.*) as b /* Use the row_to_json function on the blogs results */
FROM 
    posts p 
INNER JOIN 
    blogs ON (blogs.id=p.blog_id); /* Join blogs on the proper fields */
```

Returns:

```
{
    id: 3,
    name: 'test',
    published_at: 2015-10-08,
    blog_id: 2,
    b: {
        id:2,
        name:"test 2"
    }
}
```

Here's a great tutorial on them:
http://bender.io/2013/09/22/returning-hierarchical-data-in-a-single-sql-query/

Answer (score -1):

If you change your query to

```
'SELECT * FROM posts, blogs WHERE posts.id = blogs.id;'
```

you should have your column names prefixed with either 'posts' or 'blogs'

If you want a nested result like above, you'll have to run some manual processing.

```
res.map(d => {
   return {
     id: d.posts_id
     b : {
         id: d.blogs_id
     }
   };
});
```

Comment: Why does it prefix them in that case? Is this a feature of `pg`?

Comment: sorry - i'm not sure what your table looks like.  but if you select * from (table1, table2) the fields from table1 will be prefixed with table1_

Comment: Right but I'm asking you if that's a feature of the node `pg` package, or true of Postgres in general. For example, if I type `SELECT posts_id FROM posts, blogs WHERE posts.id = blogs.id` then it does not work. Where is this documented?